Outside Hose Pressure 3/4” to 1/2” Spigot
Will get far better water pressure if I install a 3/4” inch spigot on my 3/4” inch supply line that comes straight from the meter that is linked to my irrigation line.
It’s city water. The pressure is better on the hose bib but when they installed the spigot for me, they installed a 1/2” brass spigot that doesn’t have nearly the amount of pressure I have on the 3/4” hose spigot.
Will it increase if I remove the 1/2” and plumb in a 3/4” spigot on the 3/4” inch supply line?

Flow will increase, but pressure not so much

What is the size of the line after the spigot?  If the line after is 3/4, then the 1/2 is a restriction to the flow.

At 1GPM flow rate, pressure through a 1/4" outlet will be greater than it will be through a 1" outlet.

@freeman: But if the pipe expands again, you lose that pressure due to the flow limitations. Helpful at a spray nozzle, but at a tap it would just restrict flow.
